Error while building openbabel due to missing symbols
Got an error at 76% while trying to build OpenBabel on linux.
 [76%] Built target openbabel
 [ 76%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/babel
 /usr/bin/ld: attempted static link of dynamic object `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-     gnu/12/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so'
 /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/libstdc++.a(eh_globals.o): undefined reference to   symbol '__tls_get_addr@@GLIBC_2.3'
 /usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 make[2]: *** [tools/CMakeFiles/babel.dir/build.make:101: bin/babel] Error 1
 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1019: tools/CMakeFiles/babel.dir/all] Error 2
 make: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2

I tried adding different commands to the cmake line but I keep getting the same error. Anyone has any idea what to do?
